# regex word matching and extracting next word

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with this regex expression. I want to extract first word after `Manufacturer Part Number:`, in this case it's `laml005`.

The one that nearly does the job is this one: `Manufacturer Part Number:(.*)`

However, it gets whole line `laml005 EAN: 731084217335`, and I just need `laml005`.

String:

```
about the condition\nBrand: mure\nManufacturer Part Number: laml005 EAN: 731084217335
```

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) What flavour of REGEX - JS? PHP?

Comment: The regex is there, in the question, just formatting was a bit off.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that `.*` matches any char other than a newline, and `*` is a greedy quantifier matching zero or more instances of the construct/symbol before it. So, `.*` can't but get you the whole rest of the line.

You can use `\S+` to only capture 1 or more non-whitespace symbols, or `\w+` to match 1 or more word chars after `Manufacturer Part Number:`:

```
/Manufacturer Part Number:\s*(\S+)/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pU4xC3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

String str ="A B: C";

```
    String splitted[] = str.split(" ");

    System.out.println(splitted[0]);
```

Comment: it needs to be regex expression, this for parsehub app